# How to clear Form fields after actionListener is fired?

Tags: java, forms, jsf-2, actionlistener, managed-bean

I have a managed bean placed in view scope. Here is the bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "adminController")
@ViewScoped
public class AdminController extends BaseWebController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1019716974557397635L;

    private transient CustomerDTO customerDTO;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        customerDTO = new CustomerDTO();
    }

    public void saveCustomer(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(customerDTO.isActive());
        try {
            getServiceProvider().getCustomerService().addNewCustomer(customerDTO);
            getFacesContext().addMessage(null, FacesMessageUtils.getMessageForCustomerAddSuccess(getFacesContext()));
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            getFacesContext().addMessage(null, FacesMessageUtils.getMessageForCustomerAddError(getFacesContext()));
            printStackTrace(throwable);
        }       

    }

    public CustomerDTO getCustomerDTO() {
        return customerDTO;
    }

    public void setCustomerDTO(CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
        this.customerDTO = customerDTO;
    }   
}
```

The view is:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

    <p:panel header="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.header']}"
        id="addCustomerPanel" toggleable="true">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="addCustomerTable"
            styleClass="addCustomerTable">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputLabel id="header"
                    value="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.addCustomerTable.header']}" />
            </f:facet>

            <p:outputLabel for="customerName"
                value="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.addCustomerTable.customerName']}" />
            <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                <p:inputText id="customerName" styleClass="customerName"
                    autocomplete="off"
                    label="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.addCustomerTable.customerName']}"
                    value="#{adminController.customerDTO.customerName}" required="true" />
                <pe:tooltip for="customerName"
                    value="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.addCustomerTable.customerName.tooltip']}"
                    showEffect="slideToggle" hideEffect="slideToggle" showDelay="0"
                    myPosition="left center" atPosition="right center" />
            </h:panelGroup>

            <p:outputLabel for="customerId"
                value="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.addCustomerTable.customerId']}" />
            <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                <p:inputText id="customerId" autocomplete="off"
                    label="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.addCustomerTable.customerId']}"
                    value="#{adminController.customerDTO.customerId}" required="true">
                    <f:validator validatorId="customerIDValidator" />
                </p:inputText>
                <pe:tooltip for="customerId"
                    value="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.addCustomerTable.customerId.tooltip']}"
                    showEffect="slideToggle" hideEffect="slideToggle" showDelay="0"
                    myPosition="left center" atPosition="right center" />
            </h:panelGroup>

            <p:outputLabel for="activeStatus"
                value="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.addCustomerTable.activeStatus']}" />
            <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="activeStatus" value="#{adminController.customerDTO.active}" />  
            </h:panelGroup>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="#{adbBundle['saveButton']}"
                    actionListener="#{adminController.saveCustomer}"
                    icon="ui-icon-check" update=":growl, @form" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>

</ui:composition>
```

The problem that I am facing is, after the `actionListener` successfully executed the input fields are holding the values.

The `h:form` is not visible in the aforementioned xhtml, it is placed in the parent page as:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/globalTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">#{adbBundle['home']}</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
        <h:form id="form">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/addCustomer.xhtml" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

However if I add `customerDTO = new CustomerDTO();` at the end of the `actionListener` `saveCustomer`, the inputs are reset.

Is it the way to clear the form? Or there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use reset button to clear text or call new object of entity

Comment: @MohammodHossain thanks, so to use a reset button I need to add it in the view then associate another `actionListerner` with it, then I can create a object from that `actionListener`. Isn't it do the same thing, what I am doing by instantiating a new `CustomerDTO` at the end of the `saveCustomer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear form data using ActionEvent on button

```
public void clear(){
    customerDTO = new CustomerDTO();
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it do the same thing, what I am doing by instantiating a new `CustomerDTO` at the end of the `saveCustomer`?